# Why isn't it possible to assign the result of std::bind to a function pointer

Tags: c++

The result of an std::bind can be assigned to an std::function
  A function pointer can be assigned to an std::function.

So far I was under the impression std::function can generally hold any function pointer. And anything an std::function can hold can be assigned to a function pointer.
And found that the reult of an std::bind can't be assigned to a function pointer

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
   return x+y;
}

int main()
{

   std::function<int (int, int)> fp = &add; // a func pointor can be  assined to an std::function
   int result = fp(3,5) // this works fine

   std::function<int (int, int)> add_v2 = std::bind(&add, _1,_2); // std:: bind can be assigned to an std::function

   int result = add_v2(3,5); // works fine

   int (*add_v3)(int, int);
   add_v3 =  std::bind(&add, _1,_2); // does not compile

}
```

Can you please explain why I can't assign the result of std::bind to a function pointr

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: "And anything an std::function can hold can be assigned to a function pointer." <- I think you'll find that's not actually true.

Comment: No, a `std::function` cannot be assigned to a function pointer, but that's besides the point. The biggest problem here is that no self-respecting compiler will accept the first line of `main()` as valid C++ code, for the obvious reasons, despite the comment's claim to the contrary. This invalidates the credibility of this entire question.

Comment: Actually, @SamVarshavchik, `int main()` is a perfectly legal main function.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function  You might be confusing it with `void main()` which is not.

Comment: @DaveS - is the "first line of main()": `std::function<int (int, int) fp = &add;` valid C++, according to you? I was very specific in my comment. That's the first line of `main`, as written. Is this valid C++ code? What C++ compiler will accept this line, in any context, without complaint? I am anxiously waiting for your answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik First line is rather vague. It was unclear as to whether you referring to the `int main()`, `{`, the empty line, of the `std::function...` line. All of those can be reasonably interpreted as `"the first line"`.

Comment: So, @vandench -- if I were to tell you that there's a problem with "the first line of main()", you wouldn't be able immediately tell, precisely, what I was referring to, when you scanned through the code, looking for the start of `main()`? And when you found it, you didn't immediately see the big honking typo, that pretty much invalidates the premise of the entire question? Ok, I guess everyone's saying that I'm the only one who spotted it right away, without too much trouble. Sorry for the confusion, folks. I'm so relieved. And here I was, concerned about my job security...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don’t know of many jobs that hire people who refuse to be able to see how their statements may have been vague and confusing. But if you do manage to find a job looking for those qualities, then congratulations Mr. Trump.

Comment: Thank you for your kind compliment, @vandench -- but I just want to make sure -- just for my own records, that you did or did not see the big honking typo, despite the massive vagueness of my reference, and had considerable trouble spotting it. Can you clarify that for me, please? Was it necessary for me to reproduce the exact line in question, in my comment, before the problem became apparent, to you? You were not able to immediately spot it, because you were relying on my very, very, confusing direction, and were seeing only something that was only a line or two aray?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Given that OP was asking about an error pertaining to `std::function` and `std::bind` I hadn’t really noticed the rather minor type that likely resulted from retyping the code into SO. I also read your comment and immediately assumed you were talking about the function prototype which led me to confusion over that instead of lack of `>`.

Comment: You see, @vandench, one quickly learns very quickly with C++ is that just because there's a failure to compile, or a runtime crash, on one particular line, it doesn't mean that this particular line is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere else. Some other type is not declared correctly, for example, so you get a compilation error or a runtime crash somewhere else, which would actually be correct if the original type was declared correctly. So, when presented a problem, you have to examine all of it, and not just the alleged line with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` knows how to invoke calls to multiple callable types, including plain functions, lambdas, and the result of `std::bind()`.  Just because `std::function` can handle multiple callable types does not means the individual types are interchangeable/assignable with each other.

The return value of `std::bind()` returns a callable object of an *unspecified* type determined by the implementation.  That type has an `operator()` that `std::function` calls. The bound object carries state information about the target object and class method it needs to call inside its `operator()`. So, by definition, such an object could never be assignable to a plain function pointer. There would be nowhere to store the state data, or even the bound object's own `this` pointer.  The same reasons why a *capturing* lambda cannot be assigned to a plain function pointer, either.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_v3 =  std::bind(&add, _1,_2); // does not compile
```

As just the most obvious reason this can't be made to work, consider that all that's left after this line of code executes is a naked pointer. What can it point to?

The resulting bound function (the result of binding `add` to `_1` and `_2`) clearly didn't exist before this line of code executes. And whatever `std::bind` created, it's a temporary that will no longer exist after this line executes.

So what could `add_v3`, a simple raw pointer, possibly point to? What would own it? What would manage its lifetime? When would it be destroyed?