std::bind fails conversion claiming a different base class
I'm trying to modify a C example code to C++, embedding the functions into a class. So far I created this basic class:
#pragma once

#include <freertos/event_groups.h>
#include <esp_event.h>

class Network
{
public:
    Network();
    void wifi_init_sta;

private:
    int _retry;
    EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;

    void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data);
};

The problem is about these lines:
esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                    ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                    &event_handler,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &instance_any_id));

ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT,
                                                    IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,
                                                    &event_handler,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &instance_got_ip));

esp_event_handler_instance_register has this signature:
esp_err_t esp_event_handler_instance_register(esp_event_base_t event_base,
                                              int32_t event_id,
                                              esp_event_handler_t event_handler,
                                              void *event_handler_arg,
                                              esp_event_handler_instance_t *context)

and esp_event_handler_t this:
typedef void         (*esp_event_handler_t)(void* event_handler_arg,
                                    esp_event_base_t event_base,
                                    int32_t event_id,
                                    void* event_data);

since I put the event_handler function inside my class, I'm aware I need to use std::bind in order to provide the "hidden" this argument, but:
esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT, 
                                    ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, 
                                    std::bind(&Network::event_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4), 
                                    NULL, 
                                    &instance_any_id);

does not compile:
no suitable conversion function from "std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Network::*)(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data), Network *, const std::_Placeholder<1> &, const std::_Placeholder<2> &, const std::_Placeholder<3> &, const std::_Placeholder<4> &>::type" (aka "std::_Bind<void (Network::*(Network *, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>, std::_Placeholder<4>))(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)>") to "esp_event_handler_t" (aka "void (*)(void *event_handler_arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data)") exists C/C++(413)

I cannot spot in the error message where my error is.
It says that it cannot find a suitable conversion from:
void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data

to:
void *event_handler_arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void *event_data

the only thing that changes is the prefix: void (Network::*) vs void (*).
Of course I've specified my class, it's the reason why I'm using std::bind.
How should I change the syntax of this statement?

The problem is you can't convert a bind object to a function pointer. The rest are irrelevant. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53892475/3966456

@WeijunZhou ok, so instead of bind what should I use in order to use a member function in this specific case?

@Mark Write a static function that will call your member function. The object should be passed via event_handler_arg.

In general non-static member functions of a class cannot be converted to ("C"-style) function pointers. You could try a lamba expression [](void* obj){ reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj)->memberfn()) which is a variant of what @Yksisarvinen proposes. (Lambdas without captures can be converted to function pointers)

Does this answer your question? How do I hand over a pointer to a non-static member method to an extern "C" function?

Following the hint of user Yksisarvinen I solved with this code:
static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    static_cast<Network *>(arg)->EventHandler(arg, event_base, event_id, event_data);
}

void Network::EventHandler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    // do something
}

and:
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT, 
                                    ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, 
                                    &event_handler, 
                                    this, 
                                    &instance_any_id));


Note that you can use a static member function as well. That way EventHandler can be made private as it probably should.

@AndreyTurkin if I'm not wrong, making the function static would prevent me from accessing the other non-static members of the class.

well yeah, you need an instance for that. But you can get that instance same way you have it in your event_handler. Except in static member function, you then get to access private members because it is a member function of same class.
